# how to reuse linq method already defined in other class library

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two data access class libraries, A.csproj and B.csproj. Each has an edmx.  The two edmx contain entities from two different databases. The A.csproj refererences B.DLL. The class A in A.csproj uses LINQ to query entities in A.edmx to return IEnumerable<dtoResultA>.  So does the class B in B.csproj to B.edmx to return IEnumerable<dtoResultB>.

What should I do in order to call getUserBenefitDetail() defined in B.csproj directly as part of the LINQ query from classA.getUserStuff()?

## A.csproj

```
public class dtoResultA{
      int userID {get;set;}
      IEnumerable<userPermissions> permissions{get;set;}
      IEnumerable<dtoResultB> benefits{get;set;}
}  

public class A{
  public IEnumerable<dtoResultA> getUserStuff(int UserId){
    var result = from p in contextA.userPermission.Where(x=>x.userId = UserId)
                 let b = getUserBenefitDetail(UserId) /*<--not sure how */
                 select new dtoResultA{
                   userID = c.userId,
                   permissions = p,
                   benefits = b
                 }
  }
}
```

## B.csproj

```
public class B{
  public IEnumerable<dtoResultB> getUserBenefitDetail(int UserId){
    var result = from b in contextB.benefits.Where(x=>x.userId = UserId)
                 select new dtoResultB{
                   userID = c.userId,
                   benefits = b,
                   beneficiaries = b.beneficiaries
                 }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the big deal, you already reference B.dll in A, now isn't calling a function in B from A straightforward? Have you typed the namespace of class `B` in your `A` file?

Comment: Make **getUserBenefitDetail** method as a static method. Then you can call easily using the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem because you have 2 projects. This is a problem because you have defining a class B with a method, but you have no instance of B, and you need an instance for calling a method.

You have the choice to create an instance of B, or to make your method static. A static method can be called without an instance, it's not really a method anymore, it is more like a function.

With an instance :

```
public class A
{
  public IEnumerable<dtoResultA> getUserStuff(int UserId)
  {
    var bInstance = new B();
    var result = from p in contextA.userPermission.Where(x=>x.userId = UserId)
                 let b = bInstance.getUserBenefitDetail(UserId)
                 select new dtoResultA
                 {
                   userID = c.userId,
                   permissions = p,
                   benefits = b
                 }
  }
}
```

With a static class :

```
public class B
{
  public static IEnumerable<dtoResultB> getUserBenefitDetail(int UserId)
  {
    return stuff.....
  }
}

public class A
{
  public IEnumerable<dtoResultA> getUserStuff(int UserId)
  {
    var result = from p in contextA.userPermission.Where(x=>x.userId = UserId)
                 let b = B.getUserBenefitDetail(UserId)
                 select new dtoResultA
                 {
                   userID = c.userId,
                   permissions = p,
                   benefits = b
                 }
  }
}
```

It's up to you, what make sense, and what doesn't make sense from an objet oriented point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is:

```
public class A{
  public IEnumerable<dtoResultA> getUserStuff(int UserId){
    var result = from p in contextA.userPermission.Where(x=>x.userId = UserId)
                 select new dtoResultA{
                   userID = c.userId,
                   permissions = p,
                   benefits = getUserBenefitDetail(UserId)
                 }
  }
}
```